# Get the difference between two video frames as a percentage

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare frames of a video and to find out the similarity of the frames.
The result should be something like a percentage

Do you have any idea guys?

Thanks

Comment: [Do _you_ have any ideas?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Whet exactly is the issue you're facing? What code have you written? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Also, is it okay to just compare corresponding pixels, or do you need to e.g. track motion?

Comment: I already did some decent research but without sucess (most examples results in some numpy diagrams or something like that and not a percentage or number). I don't want to track motion - just wanna know how different image A is to image B.

Comment: You're looking for [algorithm recommendations and that's not allowed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Use Google etc. to find blogs, tutorials etc. on this. Definitely say "interframe similarity rather than "between two images" which is not going to be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) to extract both videos as an image sequence and get general video stats, then use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to compare each pixel for each frame individually.